# Running a .rb script in ERB w/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I'm trying to make a webpage with rails and erb that will show the output of a premade ruby script, and can't find any answers on how to do this. Is this even possible?

Comment: can you describe a little bit more?

Comment: I think I answered your question to quickly, did you want to run the ruby script after a certain event in the page? Is that the use case you're finding a solution for?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. Make a variable for the output of your script in the controller, and then place the variable anywhere in your view to see the output.

It will probably be one big line of text though.

Comment: @Orcastraw if this is the solution please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make a variable for the output in the script of your controller (something like: @variable = something to be called in erb).

Don't forget to put the equal sign with your erb tags if you plan on outputting the result to the DOM (<%= something for output %>)